# “... i piccoli furono trascinati dal grembo delle madri / dai grembi delle madri / dai grembi della madre”

Tags: nouns, plural

> ...i vecchi e i giovani, che erano rimasti a casa, furono consumati dal fuoco, i piccoli furono trascinati *dal grembo delle madri* come pesci dalla piena; alle balie venne sottratto l'abbraccio dei loro neonati..
>   (Salvatore Lo Bue, *La storia della poesia*, Volume 1. FrancoAngeli, 2000, p.77)

Nella frase di cui sopra è per me impossibile capire se *dal grembo delle madri* è corretto o se, invece, non dovrebbe scriversi a) o b) che seguono.

a) dai grembi delle madri

b) dai grembi della madre

C'è qualcuno che risponde?

Comment: Potresti dare come esempio una frase che non sia così esplicitamente polemica nei confronti di varie situazioni molto delicate? Grazie.

Comment: Complimenti a @I.M. per aver trovato un'altra citazione pertinente!

Comment: A naso direi – ma sono aperto a conferme o correzioni – che in frasi di questo tipo le parti del corpo vadano in genere al singolare, anche se si sta parlando di più persone, così come due persone si danno *la mano*, i pagliacci si prendono a torte in *faccia*, i soldati marciano a *testa* alta, ai commensali intossicati fa male *la pancia* e così via.

Comment: @DaG Long live Google Books! :)

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Le varie versioni hanno significati diversi:

a) dal grembo delle madri: indica che ogni madre ha un grembo e che ogni bambino è stato strappato dal grembo della propria madre. Dato che i bambini sono tanti, anche le madri sono tante, per questo si ha grembo singolare e madri plurale;

b) dai grembi delle madri: non è molto corretto perché sarebbe come se ogni madre avesse più di un grembo, cosa impossibile;

c) dai grembi della madre: in questa versione, oltre a dire che una madre ha più grembi, si indica una sola madre per tutti i bambini.

Quindi, la versione corretta è quella del testo originale, mentre le altre versioni potrebbero andare bene in altri contesti.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con la conclusione, ma non mi è molto chiaro il ragionamento. Leggendo «...anche le madri sono tante, per questo si ha grembo singolare e madri plurale» verrebbe da pensare che la versione giusta debba essere invece quella con “grembi” al plurale, visto che ogni madre ne ha uno. Io direi semplicemente che in italiano è idiomatico usare il singolare in contesti così (in altre lingue si userebbe invece il plurale).

Comment: Si, le madri sono tante ma ognuna ha un solo grembo. Se si usasse grembi (e non sapessi che ogni madre può avere un solo grembo) mi verrebbe da pensare che ogni madre può avere più grembi da cui è possibile strappare un bambino. Per esempio, immaginiamo di voler strappare un chiodo dalle ruote di una macchina: dicendo strappare il chiodo dalle ruote delle macchine indica che posso avere più ruote in una macchina da cui strappare il chiodo, dicendo strappare il chiodo dalla ruota delle macchine è come se affermassi che c'è una sola ruota per ogni macchina.

Comment: D'accordo, capisco cosa dici ed è molto logico, ma le lingue naturali sono illogiche e quindi difficilmente si prestano a questo tipo di analisi. Il tuo ragionamento è universale, eppure fallisce già in inglese, in cui le persone “shake their heads” pur avendo una sola testa e così via.

Comment: Non sto parlando in generale, ma dell'italiano. L'italiano viene dal latino che è una lingua estremamente logica, oserei dire quasi matematica. Non si può dire la stessa cosa dell'inglese.

Comment: «Non sto parlando in generale, ma dell'italiano»: certo, ma se il tuo discorso fosse valido varrebbe per qualsiasi lingua. E quanto al fatto che l'italiano o il latino sarebbero logici: hai un paio di settimane libere, così vediamo insieme qualche controesempio? :-)

Answer (score 2):

"Dai grembi della madre" è sbagliato, perché implica più grembi posseduti da una sola madre (cosa impossibile).

"Dal grembo delle madri" e "dai grembi delle madri" sono corrette tutte e due, ma hanno una sfumatura differente;

Ciò che fisicamente è: ci sono diversi "specifici" grembi ciascuno posseduto da una madre;

Ciò che (per il narratore) ai fini della narrazione conta: c'è lo stesso "generico" grembo posseduto da tutte le madri;

Il punto è che è chiaro che in "i piccoli furono trascinati dal grembo delle madri" il narratore voglia focalizzare l'attenzione sulla situazione generale di "trascinamento dal grembo"; essendo in questo contesto il resto meno rilevante ai fini della narrazione, si può (e secondo me funziona bene farlo) passare da una descrizione che rispecchia la situazione "fisica" effettiva ("dai grembi delle madri", che indica gruppi di uno o più bambini separati ciascuno da un diverso "specifico" grembo ciascuno posseduto da una madre, quello che fisicamente è) ad una più generale che non rispecchia la situazione "fisica" effettiva ma che d'altro canto è molto più espressiva ("dal grembo delle madri", che indica gruppi di uno o più bambini separati ciascuno dallo stesso "generico" grembo posseduto da tutte le madri, quello che ai fini della narrazione conta).

Per me "Dal grembo delle madri" e "dai grembi delle madri" sono corrette tutte e due ma in questo caso, intuendo l'intenzione del narratore, "dal grembo delle madri" secondo me trasmette molto meglio il concetto di quanto non lo farebbe "dai grembi delle madri".